Estoy intentando enviar por contexto la data e un campo en odoo
Tendria que ser de la factura a la linea de pago pasando por el recibo.
Hice esto, pero no funciona
import logging
from odoo import models
from odoo.tools.safe_eval import safe_eval

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    def action_register_payment_group(self):
        """Metodo que envia desde la factura al grupo de pago el canal por contexto"""
        _logger.info('Entrando a la función action_register_payment_group')
        res = super(AccountMove, self).action_register_payment_group()
        _logger.info(f'Resultado de la llamada super: {res}')
        if res.get('context') and self.channel_id:
            _logger.info(f'Contexto encontrado: {res.get("context")}, Channel ID: {self.channel_id.id}')
            ctx = res.get('context', '{}') or {}
            ctx.update({'default_channel_id': self.channel_id.id})
            _logger.info(f'Contexto actualizado: {ctx}')
            res['context'] = ctx
        else:
            _logger.info('No se encontró contexto o channel_id no está definido')
        return res

import logging
from odoo import api, fields, models
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AccountPaymentGroup(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.payment.group"

    channel_id = fields.Many2one('mirgor.channels', string="Channel")

    def payment_id(self):
        """Metodo que envia desde la factura al grupo de pago el canal por contexto"""
        _logger.info('Entrando a la función payment_id')
        res = super(AccountPaymentGroup, self).payment_id()
        _logger.info(f'Resultado de la llamada super: {res}')
        if res.get('context') and self.channel_id:
            _logger.info(f'Contexto encontrado: {res.get("context")}, Channel ID: {self.channel_id.id}')
            ctx = res.get('context', '{}') or {}
            ctx.update({'default_channel_id': self.channel_id.id})
            _logger.info(f'Contexto actualizado: {ctx}')
            res['context'] = ctx
        else:
            _logger.info('No se encontró contexto o channel_id no está definido')
        return res
import logging
from odoo import api, fields, models
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AccountPayment_(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment'

    @api.model
    def _get_channel_id(self):
        _logger.info('Entrando a la función _get_channel_id')
        if self._context.get('default_channel_id', False):
            channel_id = self._context.get('default_channel_id')
            _logger.info(f'Canal ID encontrado en el contexto: {channel_id}')
            return channel_id
        _logger.info('No se encontró default_channel_id en el contexto')

    channel_id = fields.Many2one('mirgor.channels', string="Channel", default=_get_channel_id)


¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Me parece que la explicación que das no deja ver claramente el problema que tienes. Quizás falta explicar cómo el código falla o qué es exactamente lo que esperas que pase y no está pasando, o si tienes un mensaje de error, cuál es ese error exactamente y en qué momento ocurre. Para más información lee [ask]. Vaya, ¡Casi 70 líneas de código y una explicación de 1 línea que no dice nada!

res no contiene el contexto. El contexto debe de tomarse desde self.env.context.get('tu-campo') o alguna otra asignación de self.env

No defines que versión de odoo estas usando. Actualmente la 18 está por salir, la 17 esta como versión nueva y la 16 paso estable, la v15 es ya legacy,  y la v14 ya no se le va dar mantenimiento. Estas versiones tienen muchos cambios entre ellas.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
